# initializing a pointer to const type to a non-const type

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Is it possible?

I mean something like this:

```
const int *a;
int x=6;
a=&x;
```

Another question is whether it's possible to continue from above to this:

```
int const *b = a;
```

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's not a constant pointer. The pointer points to constant data.

Comment: @sharth: True, my wording was slightly sloppy. (Speaking of which, `const` does not mean "constant"; a constant expression can be evaluated at compile time, whereas `const` means "read-only". Consider the perfectly valid `const int r = rand();`; `r` is `const` but not constant.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'll mostly agree. I'll also point out Section 6.7.6.1 Paragraph 3 of C 2011: _The following pair of declarations demonstrates the difference between a "variable pointer to a constant value" and a "constant pointer to a variable value"._ So it's not just me that could be using clearer words :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You're right, I was wrong (just not paying sufficient attention). `a` is a pointer to `const int`, which means you can't modify `x` *via that pointer*. I'll delete my original comment.

Answer (score 3):

You may convert a pointer to an object type to a pointer to a different object type. In particular, you may convert an `int *` to a `const int *` and vice-versa.

You may not modify an object defined with `const` even if you do so through a pointer to non-const type.

`const int` and `int const` are the same thing, so `int const *b = a;` is permitted.

`a = &x;` is permitted; it is safe to convert a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `const int`.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's iterate through some declarations:

1. A pointer to a constant integer. The following two declarations are identical.

   ```
   const int * x;
   int const * x;
   ```

   Additionally, the pointer is not constant here. So we can change what `x` points to.

   ```
   const int * x;
   x = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Legal
   ```

   However, we can't change the value of what x points to:

   ```
   *x = 3; // Illegal.
   ```
2. A constant pointer to an integer.

   ```
   int * const x;
   ```

   In this case, we can't change what x points to, but we can change it's contents. So...

   ```
   int * const x = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 3; // Legal
   x = NULL; // Illegal
   ```
3. We can do both of these consts at the same time too. (A constant pointer to constant data)

   ```
   const int * const x;
   int const * const x;
   ```

   And to show the illegal operations:

   ```
   int const * const x = malloc(sizeof(int));
   x = NULL; // Illegal
   *x = 3; // Illegal
   ```

Comment: http://cdecl.org is a good resource for making sure that you have the `const` in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question to

```
 int const *b = a;
```

here `a` is a pointer to a `const int`. `b` has the same type (exactly). So you can initialize `b` with `a` without any problem.

To sum up the answers given above for `a=&x;`, you can convert a pointer from a type `T` to a type `const T` safely not the other way around.  The reason is that, the conversion from type `T` to `const T` will not destroy the object, since a pointer to a const type will only read the object, not write to. But the other way conversion, from `const T` to `T`, could potential write to a `const T`.